# Why does my JSP work locally, but attempt to load errorPage upon remote deployment?

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

The JSP page has:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" errorPage="/other/error.jsp" %>
```

On my laptop (after deploying via NetBeans 7.3): I go to view the JSP on localhost:8084, and there is no trouble.

However, when viewing this remotely on Debian VPS running Tomcat7, my JSP page jumps directly to the error.jsp page indicated above.

My JSPs use: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/`

This supposedly should help to keep my paths relative.

Comment: So you are using the same version of Tomcat 7 on both your local and on Debian VPS? Is there any error present in the `logs` in the Tomcat log directory?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally discovered Catalina logs, and it was misunderstanding when I put ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ in quotes for anything with

Anyway, I resolved this issue by doing this:

```
<c:set var="myContext" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<jsp:include page="${myContext}/WEB-INF/includes/head-full.jsp" />
```

It's still not working all the way through for me, but this part is resolved at least...